# Using an EmberJS Component for Instant Filtering

Tags: ember.js

I have a simple Ember component setup:

```
<div class="instant-search">
  {{input value=filterString placeholder="Search"}}
</div>
```

I'm trying to setup a simple filter, so that whatever you type in that list, will filter the list on the model below:

```
  <tbody>
    {{#each model as |user| }}
      {{#link-to 'users.edit' user tagName="tr"}}
        <td>{{ current-status model=user }}</td>
        <td>{{ user.name }}</td>
        <td><em>{{ user.email }}</em></td>
      {{/link-to}}
    {{/each}}
  </tbody>
```

I've played around with this all day and I can't get them talking to each other. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this seems like a simple computed property in your component looking something like this (assuming you use Ember-CLI so you can use ES6).

```
filteredModel: function() {
  let model = this.get('model');
  let filter = this.get('filterString');
  return model.filter((user) => { user.get('name').indexOf(filter) === 0; });
}.property('model', 'filterString')
```

This property will update as soon as `filterString` or `model` is changed and only return the users where the name begins with `filterString`.

Then in your template you simply bind to `filteredModel` instead of `model`.

```
{{#each filteredModel as |user| }}
  ...
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I got it working, but my filteredModel block had to be the same component. Do you know how I could pass this to a different component, the one that is rendering my list?

Comment: This would work in any component as long as you have both the users and the filterString available. If you want it in your rendering component then you just have to pass filterString there as well.